# How to find the Email Address field within Disneyworld login page to send text using Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am writing a simple program to automatically login to my Disney World account. I cannot successfully locate the email address element. I have had success automating other buttons on the Disney World website, but for whatever reason, I can't locate the email address element.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

login_url = "https://disneyworld.disney.go.com/login?appRedirect=%2F"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"MY_CHROMEDRIVER_PATH")
driver.get(login_url)

print("Starting...")

try:
    email_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 8).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "")) #See below what I've tried on this line

    )
    print("Found element, sending keys...")
    email_input.send_keys("test")
except:
    print("Failed...")
    driver.quit()
```

I have tried the following with no success:

```
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input\[@type='email'\]"))

EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div\[@id='did-ui-view'\]/div/section/section/form/section/div/div/label/span\[2\]/input"))

EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ng-valid"))

EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "input-wrapper"))

EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "field-group"))

EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "field field-username-email badgeable"))
```

I have also tried many other versions of the examples above far too embarrassing to post on here. I have used the inspect element tool and tried everything I could think of. I also downloaded the Selenium IDE Chrome extension to record my keystrokes and find the exact XPATH for the element I was interacting with. I honestly don't know what else to try, which is why I'm posting this question. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element with the text as *E-Mail Login* is within an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607451/7429447) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

  - Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

    ```
    driver.get('https://disneyworld.disney.go.com/login?appRedirect=%2F')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe#disneyid-iframe")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[aria-label='Username or Email Address']"))).send_keys("TheAtypicalNerd")
    ```
  - Using *XPATH*:

    ```
    driver.get('https://disneyworld.disney.go.com/login?appRedirect=%2F')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='disneyid-iframe']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@aria-label='Username or Email Address']"))).send_keys("TheAtypicalNerd")
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: disneyworld]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)

Answer (score 0):

The login box is present inside an `iframe`, you need to switch to it before trying to interact with it.

Try the following code snippet

```
try:
    # wait or i frame to be located
    i_frame = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="disneyid-iframe"]')))

    # switch to iframe
    driver.switch_to.frame(i_frame)

    # find email input text field
    email_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="did-ui-view"]/div/section/section/form/section/div[1]/div/label/span[2]/input'))
    )
    print("Found element, sending keys...")
    email_input.send_keys("test")
except:
    print('Failed')
    driver.quit()
```